# angularjs remember me functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do remember me functionality using angularjs,but my email id is 
storing in cookies when i click remember me and after logout when i try to
relogin,my mail id should store in username field but it was not showing
what may be the problem below is my code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="checkbox" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

    <label>
        <input  ng-checked="rememberMe"  ng-click="rememberMe1();" type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>

    <div class="modal-footer">

        <div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submitLogin()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
        </div>

        <div>
```

**my angular controller:**

```
$scope.loginDetails = {
    "email": "",
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
};

};

$scope.rememberMe1 = function () {
    $cookies.put("emailId", $scope.loginDetails.email);
};

$scope.submitLogin = function () {
    var emailId = $cookies.get("emailId"); ``
    $scope.loginDetails.email = emailId;
})

}); ``

};
```

Comment: I have formatted and indented your code, and it looks incoherent. There are many closing characters in the JS and opening divs in the HTML, there's even a random double-backtick, not sure what to do with that.

Comment: no,actually i copied only some portion of code here,i wanted to know whether logic was right or not

Answer (score 3):

i believe that you'r code have so many errors and it will not even run try console.log()

### solution with local storage

first in you'r service's file add Ls service

```
App.factory("LS", function($window, $rootScope) {
    return {
        setData: function (key , val) {
            $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.setItem(key , val);
            return this;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return $window.localStorage && $window.localStorage.getItem(key);
        }
    };
});
```

in you'r file login.js add this code 

 add service LS

```
var myMail = LS.getData('emailId');
    $scope.loginDetails={
        "email":"",
        "username":"",
        "password":""
    };
    $scope.rememberMe1 = function () {
        LS.setData("emailId", $scope.loginDetails.email);
    };
    $scope.submitLogin=function(){
        $scope.loginDetails.email = myMail;
    };
```

Comment: it was working fine Emad Fani,as the code has more number of lines i couldnt post that all,i only copied some lines of code

Comment: i guess local Storage is a better solution for saving data it's faster and more reliable

Comment: if you wanted i can give you an example local storage service so you can use it anywhere

Comment: k then according to my above html file could u please let me know how can i do remember me functionality in angular

Comment: remember to change it according to you'r usage

Comment: k bro but where is the functionality bro

Comment: functionality what do u mean bro ?

Comment: u said that you would give a local storage service to implement remember me functionality.so,iam waiting for it bro thats what iam asking

Comment: bro App.factory is service to connect to local storage you should pic up you'r stored data when ever you need it
var myMail = LS.getData('key');